# MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, linq

we have a problem with mysql, entity framework 6.0 and repository pattern.
This is the error that occurred when we try to add an entity at the same time with multiple users.
We don't use IQueryable return type (like suggested in other topics).
This is the code that return error:

```
using (var dbContextTransaction = rep.Context.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
try
{
    rep.Add(newSchedule);
    rep.Save();

    dbContextTransaction.Commit();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

    dbContextTransaction.Rollback();
    Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
}

}
```

Error fired with and without database transaction.
Stack trace point to function that call this part of code.
Any idea for resolve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the exception?

Comment: Is this an MVC app? Is `rep` static?

Comment: Unexpected exception - MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first. Yes, MVC app and rep is static

Comment: Since it is static the same instance will be used for all requests. Make sure you instantiate a new instance for each request.

Comment: Thanks, we try it and let you know

Comment: @Crowcoder it works, thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EF Context is not thread safe, you need to create one context per request. Maybe you can inject a factory and ask for the context.
Or set the context as Transient in you DI container.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, now I create one context per request in helper class, it works.